# Exchange 2013 attendee response is always null

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

We have problem on Exchange 2013, response of attendee for other attendees is not retrieved from Exchange server, via EWS and also in OWA.
In Office 365 it works.

Comment: Is that for the organizer or for an attendee mailbox?

Comment: For organizer mailbox everything works. For attendee mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course - all replies only go to the organizer, the attendees never see the updated responses.

It is a recent Office 365 feature that allows the attendees to see the responses as well. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/attendees-can-see-others-responses-to-a-meeting-invitation-f51437e5-352c-4223-b7d8-7020cd71f3c8

Comment: Thank you. I found that post in Microsoft site and wanted to be sure that there is no any chance to get responses for non-organizer (attendees).